# Установка таймаута для запросов на сервер

Tags: android

Зачем ставят таймаут для запросов на сервер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если таймаута не будет и сервер решит не отвечать, вы будете ждать ответа "вечно". А с таймаутом такой зависший запрос отвалится через некоторое время в любом случае. И делают так не только на андроиде.